# More efficient version of this example of javascript function and show commands

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm relatively new to JS, but I understand some of the basic principles. However, this leads to rather inefficient and tedious code.

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient version of something that is essentially just this

*

```
function gz2() {
    $('#GZ2').show(500);
    setTimeout(gz3, 2000);
}
function gz3() {
    $('#GZ3').show(500);
    setTimeout(gz4, 2000);
}
function gz4() {
    $('#GZ4').show(500);
    setTimeout(gz5, 2000);
}
function gz5() {
    $('#GZ5').fadeIn(200);
    setTimeout(gz6, 1000);
}
function gz6() {
    $('#GZ6').fadeIn(200);
    setTimeout(gReturn, 2000);
}
function gReturn(){
    $('.gammaZ').hide();
    setTimeout(gamma1, 0)
}
```

*

To be clear, these are all set to "display:none" within the CSS and are made visible via JavaScript

Is there a code to display these elements sequentially rather than having to call each one individually? Especially if the visibility effect (show, fadeIn, slideDown) is the same for all of them? Like "all of this class, display with a two second interval until they're all visible"

I ask because this has worked... "fine" for now, but I've recently reached a point in my code where I'd have to do about 40 of these in a row with my current knowledge of JavaScript, and that's not something I feel comfortable doing not only because it's monotonous but because I'm confident there's an easier way to do it that I'm just not getting.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try a loop and closures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @ jfriend00 said in my previous answer, you can use timeout function inside the callback functions.

```
$('#GZ2').show(500, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){$('#GZ3').show(500, function(){
        setTimeout(function(){$('#GZ4').show(500, function(){
            setTimeout(function(){$('#GZ5').fadeIn(200, function(){
                setTimeout(function(){$('#GZ6').fadeIn(200, function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){$('.gammaZ').hide(), 2000};
                }, 1000};
            }, 2000};
        }), 2000};
    }), 2000};
});
```

Comment: There's really no reason for this to be a separate answer.  You can just use the edit link to add this option to your previous answer or to change it to this.

Comment: @R.Little - How does this answer help you with reuse at all for doing 40 of these in a row?  All this does is replace your named functions with anonymous functions.  I don't see how this actually improves your situation much when facing doing this for lots of objects or in multiple places in your code?  This uses no reusable code and is still hand-coded for each and every object and use.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was agitated by the concept of having to rig 40 functions and 40 settimeout commands to each of those. This is more streamlined block of code that's easily editable and reviewable so (even though it still 40 lines, that won't change) it is much easier to manage and much less of a headache for me.

Comment: @R.Little - it just seems like you should look for a table driven approach (a core function that iterates through a table of values) rather than repeating nearly the same lines of code over and over.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sequence of call back functions

```
$('#GZ2').show(500, function(){
    $('#GZ3').show(500, function(){
        $('#GZ4').show(500, function(){
            $('#GZ5').fadeIn(200, function(){
                $('#GZ6').fadeIn(200, function(){
                    $('.gammaZ').hide();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This example works, and it's concise, which is what I'm looking for! But GZ2-GZ6 go by very quickly. Is it possible to slow down the time period between when one appears and the other begins? GZ2 is set to have a 500ms visibility animation but the ".gammaZ" class has almost already hidden all of the elements by the time GZ2's animation has finished.

Comment: This answer misses the fact that the OP's code has a 2000ms delay before the next action starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can factor out a function `run` that accepts a list of calls and delays:

```
function run(L) {
    var i = 0;
    function step() {
        L[i][0]();
        if (i < L.length-1) {
            setTimeout(step, L[i++][1]);
        }
    }
    step();
 }
```

Then you can use it like:

```
run([[function(){$('#GZ2').show(500);}, 2000],
     [function(){$('#GZ3').show(500);}, 2000],
     [function(){$('#GZ4').show(500);}, 2000],
     [function(){$('#GZ5').fadeIn(200);}, 1000],
     [function(){$('#GZ6').fadeIn(200);}, 2000],
     [function(){$('.gammaZ').hide();}, 0],
     [gamma1]]);
```

Comment: I don't terribly understand the first bit of code, but it worked when i copy and pasted it. I was able to wrap both the top and bottom codes into a single function that i could call and now it works like i never changed my code at all, even though its now much more efficient. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you can use closures on the show function, check it out...

```
$('#gz1').show(500, function() {
    $('#gz2').show(2000, function() {
        $('#gz3').show(2000, function() {
            $('#gz4').show(1000, function() {
                $('#gz5').show(1000); //end of the road.
            });
        });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/toxjb9xh/

Answer (score 0):

If the goal here is to create some reusable code that you could use for many different scenarios like this (since you say "I'd have to do about 40 of these in a row"), then you typically want take the repetitive code and put it in a reusable function that takes arguments and then pass the function a table of data.

Then, you can reuse the logic in other places by just passing a different table of data to it.  This may be a little more initial code, but is much more resuable and maintenance can often be done by just editing a table of data or a new use can be coded by just creating a new table of data and calling the master function again passing that data to it:

```
function showNext(selector, method, timing, delay, callback) {
    $(selector)[method](timing);
    setTimeout(callback, delay);
}

function runItems(list, doneCallback) {
    var cntr = 0;

    function next() {
        var obj;
        if (cntr < list.length) {
            obj = list[cntr++];
            showNext(obj.selector, obj.method, obj.timing, obj.delay, next);
        } else {
            doneCallback();
        }
    }
    next();
}

var items = [
    {selector: '#GZ2', method: 'show', timing: 500, delay: 2000},
    {selector: '#GZ3', method: 'show', timing: 500, delay: 2000},
    {selector: '#GZ4', method: 'show', timing: 500, delay: 2000},
    {selector: '#GZ5', method: 'fadeIn', timing: 200, delay: 1000},
    {selector: '#GZ6', method: 'fadeIn', timing: 200, delay: 1000},
    {selector: '.gammaZ', method: 'hide', timing: 0, delay: 0},
];

runItems(items, gReturn);
```

If you create default values for various table elements in the code, you can eliminate some of the data in the table.  For example, you could make the default method be `'show'`, the default timing be `500` and the default delay be `2000` and then you could skip all the properties in the table that are the default value.